# How to parse JSON returned using the WP-API (JSON REST API WP plugin)

Tags: android, json, wordpress, rest, parsing

I just don't understand how do I parse the json data generated by JSON REST API WordPress Plugin ([Link to Plugin Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/)). Below is the JSON Array created by this plugin on my site, I want to parse it in android and display. But I don't know how to do this because this array is nested and don't have identifier/tag/name to root element.

NOT DUPLICATE: The json returned using JSON REST API is without tag and different.

JSON ARRAY partial

```
[{

    "ID": 265,
    "title": "Prince William Distressed Homes",
    "status": "publish",
    "type": "portfolio",
    "author": 

    {

        "ID": 1,
        "username": "MrDarpan",
        "name": "MrDarpan",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "MrDarpan",
        "slug": "MrDarpan",
        "URL": "",
        "avatar": "http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/fa87ce7d0b7411886af9a4a16c134075?s=96",
        "description": "",
        "registered": "2015-03-15T02:47:06+00:00",
        "meta": 

        {

              "links": 

                     {
                       "self": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/users/1",
                       "archives": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/users/1/posts"
                     }
        }

    },
    "content": "<!-- meta slider -->\n<div style=\"max-width: 682px; margin: 0 auto;\" class=\"metaslider metaslider-flex metaslider-268 ml-slider nav-hidden\">\n \n <div id=\"metaslider_container_268\">\n <div id=\"metaslider_268\">\n <ul class=\"slides\">\n <li style=\"display: block; width: 100%;\" class=\"slide-266 ms-image\"><img src=\"http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Prince-William-Distressed-Homes-1.jpg\" height=\"459\" width=\"682\" alt=\"Prince William Distressed Homes\" class=\"slider-268 slide-266\" title=\"Prince William Distressed Homes\" /><div class=\"caption-wrap\"><div class=\"caption\">Prince William Distressed Homes Landing Page by Darpan Kulkarni</div></div></li>\n <li style=\"display: none; width: 100%;\" class=\"slide-267 ms-image\"><img src=\"http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Prince-William-Distressed-Homes-2.jpg\" height=\"459\" width=\"682\" alt=\"Prince William Distressed Homes\" class=\"slider-268 slide-267\" title=\"Prince William Distressed Homes\" /><div class=\"caption-wrap\"><div class=\"caption\">Prince William Distressed Homes Landing Page by Darpan Kulkarni</div></div></li>\n </ul>\n </div>\n \n </div>\n <script type=\"text/javascript\">\n var metaslider_268 = function($) {\n $('#metaslider_268').addClass('flexslider'); // theme/plugin conflict avoidance\n $('#metaslider_268').flexslider({ \n slideshowSpeed:3000,\n animation:\"fade\",\n controlNav:false,\n directionNav:true,\n pauseOnHover:true,\n direction:\"horizontal\",\n reverse:false,\n animationSpeed:600,\n prevText:\"&lt;\",\n nextText:\"&gt;\",\n slideshow:true\n });\n };\n var timer_metaslider_268 = function() {\n var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_268, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_268, 1) : metaslider_268(window.jQuery);\n };\n timer_metaslider_268();\n </script>\n</div>\n<!--// meta slider-->\n",
    "parent": 0,
    "link": "http://darpankulkarni.in/portfolio/prince-william-distressed-homes/",
    "date": "2015-03-21T05:36:15+00:00",
    "modified": "2015-03-21T05:36:15+00:00",
    "format": "standard",
    "slug": "prince-william-distressed-homes",
    "guid": "http://darpankulkarni.in/?post_type=portfolio&#038;p=265",
    "excerpt": null,
    "menu_order": 0,
    "comment_status": "closed",
    "ping_status": "closed",
    "sticky": false,
    "date_tz": "UTC",
    "date_gmt": "2015-03-21T05:36:15+00:00",
    "modified_tz": "UTC",
    "modified_gmt": "2015-03-21T05:36:15+00:00",
    "meta":
        {

         "links": 

               {
                 "self": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/posts/265",
                 "author": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/users/1",
                 "collection": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/posts",
                 "replies": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/posts/265/comments",
                 "version-history": "http://darpankulkarni.in/wp-json/posts/265/revisions"
               }

        },

        {
           //More items in array
        },
  }]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: The json returned using JSON REST API is without tag and different. also nested.

Comment: Please don't expect us to help you with exact code that you want to solve your problem. You need to figure that out yourself. SO is not code providing service. The link I have given contains more than enough information to know about json parsing. Rest you need to figure out yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below snippet for parsing:

```
public parseJson(String jsonMessage){
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            // Setting values in objects..
             Object object = jsonParser.parse(jsonMessage);
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;

        Iterator j = jsonArray.iterator();
        while (j.hasNext()) {
            JSONObject innerObj;
            Object value = j.next();
            if(value instanceof JSONObject){
                innerObj = (JSONObject)value;
                String id =  (String) innerObj.get("ID");
                String title =  (String) innerObj.get("title");
                String status =  (String) innerObj.get("status");
                String type =  (String) innerObj.get("type");
                JSONObject author= (JSONObject) innerObj.get("author");
                String authorId =  (String)author.get("authorId");
                String username =  (String)author.get("username");
                String name =  (String)author.get("name");
                String firstName =  (String)author.get("firstName");
                String lastName =  (String)author.get("lastName");
                String nickname =  (String)author.get("nickname");
                String authorSlug =  (String)author.get("slug");
                String URL =  (String)author.get("URL");
                String avatar =  (String)author.get("avatar");
                String description =  (String)author.get("description");
                String registered =  (String)author.get("registered");
                JSONObject meta= (JSONObject) author.get("meta");
                JSONObject links= (JSONObject) meta.get("links");
                String self =  (String)links.get("self");
                String archives =  (String)links.get("archives");
                String parent= (String) innerObj.get("parent");
                String link= (String) innerObj.get("link");
                String date= (String) innerObj.get("date");
                String modified= (String) innerObj.get("modified");
                String format= (String) innerObj.get("format");
                String slug= (String) innerObj.get("slug");
                String guid= (String) innerObj.get("guid");
                String excerpt= (String) innerObj.get("excerpt");
                String menu_order= (String) innerObj.get("menu_order");
                String comment_status= (String) innerObj.get("comment_status");
                String ping_status= (String) innerObj.get("ping_status");
                String sticky= (String) innerObj.get("sticky");
                String date_tz= (String) innerObj.get("date_tz");
                String date_gmt= (String) innerObj.get("date_gmt");
                String modified_tz= (String) innerObj.get("modified_tz");
                String modified_gmt= (String) innerObj.get("modified_gmt");
}
}
```